# Verify transaction was sent by known public address

Tags: transaction-confirmation, address-verification

Is there a way to check/verify if a transaction was sent by a specific known public address?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

No.

[The sender can prove that they sent a certain amount to a certain address, using the tx key.](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/prove-payment.html) Even so, this does not reveal their wallet address.

Comment: ok, thx. So there's no way to link the public address of an outgoing transaction without running the synced full wallet in MoneroGUI or CLI  (private spend key)? The use case is to prove to another party that the transaction originates from exactly this wallet and no other wallet.